# Keep the score of a game in javascript

Tags: javascript

When a user clicks the dice are rolling:

```
function launch(){ //random images of the dice
    var images = ["images/dice-1.jpg","images/dice-2.jpg","images/dice-3.jpg","images/dice-4.jpg","images/dice-5.jpg","images/dice-6.jpg"];
    var random1 = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    var random2 = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    document.getElementById("firstimage").src =random1;
    document.getElementById("secondimage").src =random2;
}
```

Then, if the dice are the same (have the same src) I want to increase the score in a cell:

```
var scoreofplayer = 0;

function check(){//check if the dices are the same
    var dice1 = getElementById('firstimage').getAttribute('src');
    var dice2 = getElementById('secondimage').getAttribute('src');  
    if (dice1 == dice2){
        scoreofplayer +=1;
        document.getElementById('scor1').innerHTML=scoreofplayer;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Score</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="firstname"></td>
    <td id="scor1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="launch();">Role dice</button>
<div id="zaruri" style="width:450px;height:300px;">
                <img id = "firstimage" src="images/dice-1.jpg" />
                <img id = "secondimage" src="images/dice-1.jpg" />
            </div>
```

Nothing appears in `scor1` cell. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are your 'firstimage' and 'secondimage' elements in HTML? I can't see them in your HTML?

Comment: the document.getElementByID has score1 and the td element has scor1? is it a typo error in the question or in your program?

Comment: `'scor1' !== 'score1'`. Also, what's `numberofclicks()`?

Comment: sorry, it is a typo in the question, still nothing shows. @RaiAmmadKhan I will update with all my html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get an element with an id of `score1` in your JavaScript, but have an element with an id of `scor1` in your HTML. There's an E missing.

Your 'onclick' handler in your HTML is also calling a function `numberofclicks()` that you haven't included; the code you posted has a function called `check()`.

Comment: It was a typo in the question. Sorry. Still nothing shows.

Comment: Now you've updated your code, and you're not calling `check()` anywhere. You've got to run the code for it to update the score (and the display). Can you set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If you change your JSFiddle options to "No wrap - in <head>" (under the 'Frameworks and extensions' panel on the left), and uncomment your innerHTML line in `numberofclicks()`, your code seems to work OK.

Comment: `numberofclicks()` gets only the number of clicks. I want to use the score: if dice1==dice2 they get one point. `var scoreofplayer` increases. but it does not output

Comment: I've fixed up your jsfiddle so it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/GUR7z/

As well as the missing `document` in front of the `getElementById()` call, I had to move your `check()` function declaration outside of the `document.ready` call so it was accessible in the onclick handler.

Comment: Ok, thanks. so you cannot call a function that is in document.ready? it is out of scope? why then put functions there?

Comment: If you define a function within another function, then that function is only available within that function. That's what you'd done in your `document.ready` - defined a function `check` within the anonymous function. It's better to define functions outside of `document.ready`, and call them within `document.ready` if they shouldn't be run until the entire page has loaded.

Comment: great explanation. somebody taught me otherwise. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made a really silly mistake, maybe because I'm tired:
`getElementById('firstimage').getAttribute('src');` should be `document.getElementById('firstimage').getAttribute('src');`